Try to create custom geometry on Procore BIM Web viewer
I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@procore/bim-webviewer-sdk SDK in our app. And I want to add some tessellation geometry on Procore BIM web viewer.
Is it possible to add tessellation geometry on Procore BIM web viewer ?

The Procore BIM Web Viewer SDK (@procore/bim-webviewer-sdk) does not natively support adding custom tessellation geometry directly to the viewer out of the box. The SDK is designed primarily to render and interact with BIM (Building Information Modeling) models, typically using formats like IFC or glTF, which already contain pre-defined geometry.
Directly adding tessellation geometry to the Procore BIM Web Viewer is not natively supported, but you can overlay custom geometry using a combination of external 3D libraries like three.js alongside the SDK. This would involve manually positioning and managing the geometry to ensure it aligns with the BIM model.
